# Как запустить std::async без блокировки фьючерса? С++

Tags: c++, многопоточность

В стандартной библиотеке есть такая замечательная штука, как [std::async](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async), которая позволяет толкнуть функцию планировщику задач. Проблема следующая: есть функция, которую просто нужно запустить параллельно. Меня не интересует возвращаемое значение, меня не интересует синхронизация, поскольку эта функция не имеет сайд эффектов. Она просто выводит текст через некоторый таймаут:

```
void foo()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(10s);
}
```

Однако при попытке запустить такую функцию через std::async мы столкнёмся с блокировкой:

```
auto f = std::async(std::launch::async, foo);
```

Поскольку [деструктор](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/%7Efuture) фьючерса будет выполнен ДО окончания выполнения задачи. Таким образом задача не будет выполнена параллельно - основной поток будет ждать завершения std::async.

Как этого избежать?

Comment: "Фьючерс" - это штука, которой торгуют на бирже. Тут просто future, без "с". :P

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Скотт Майерс с вами не согласен)

Comment: Цитату из книги приведете? Не очень понимаю, при чем тут он, если это проблема только русского перевода.

Comment: *"выводит текст через некоторый таймаут"* - это значит, что функция имеет сайд эффекты. Собственно почему бы не воспользоваться каким-нибуль многопоточным логерром или системой событий?

Comment: @user7860670 приведите минимальный пример, пожалуйста. И "выводит текст через некоторый таймаут" - это лишь сильно упрощенный пример, чтобы вы понимали, что именно меня интересует.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Без проблем: "*стратегия std: : launch : : deferred означает, что f может выполняться только тогда, когда для **фьючерса**, возвращенного std : : async, вызывается функция-член get 
или wait2*" - Глава 7, Часть 7.2. Скотт Майерс "Эффективный и современный С++"

Comment: Ого. Только сам Скотт Майерс тут не при чем. Это особенности (кривизна?) перевода.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ну. тем не менее, эта "кривизна перевода" в обиходе :)

Comment: Минимальный пример чего именно? Попробуйте https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer2.html - по сути там есть из коробки этот самый async, только не возвращающий futere, выполняющийся в контролируемом вами потоке, а заодно и не требующий отдельного `sleep` (который кстати категорически нельзя делать в `std::async`, так как это может привести к простою всех потоков из пула).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для такого случая лучшее решение `thread` с вызовом `detach`. Для этого `async`, пожалуй, несколько тяжеловесен — вас же не интересует ни возвращаемое значение, ни перехват могущих быть исключений...

Но можно и с `async` игнорировать возврат, если просто использовать не фьючерс, а указатель на него.

```
future<void> * f = new future<void>(std::async(std::launch::async, foo));
```

И все. Можете забыть про него до окончания программы :), можете через какое-то время вызвать `delete`...

Такой вариант годится?

Comment: Вряд ли годится. Первый вариант не имеет тех преимуществ, что дает std::async - мы можем положить программу, если потоков в системе не будет хватать. К тому же async должен работать быстрее, когда много вызовов, насколько я знаю. Второй же вариант - это искуственная утечка памяти. А когда вызывать delete - неизвестно

Comment: Неужели кроме thread нет никакой другой возможности сохранть преимущества std::async, но не застревать в блокировке?

Comment: А откуда такая информация, что `async` быстрее `thread`? Насколько я понимаю, все преимущества `async` в получении возвращаемого значения (не надо заморачиваться с синхронизацией и т.п. в `thread`) и в корректной обработке и передаче могущего возникнуть в `thread` исключения. И то, и другое при отсоединении потока становится невозможным, так что `async` просто не имеет такой опции...

Comment: На счет быстрее - не уверен, где-то слышал, что там используется пул потоков и благодаря этому не создается поток каждый новый вызов, что является тяжелой операцией. К тому же async обрабатывает ситуацию, когда у нас возникает ограничение подписки или кончаются программные потоки

Comment: У Мейерса по сути говорится, что `async` просто берет на себя большой кусок работы программиста по сравнению с работой с `thread`, но ничего не говорит о производительности. Если у вас программа, где могут закончиться программные потоки — то `async` эту проблему решает тем, что откладывает выполнение вашей функции до освобождения, так что вы даже не будете об этом знать :) Еще у него для `async` (цитирую): *Либо гарантируется вызов get или wait для фьючерса, возвращаемого `async`, либо ситуация, когда задача не выполняется совсем, является приемлемой*.

Comment: Ну, или просто продляйте тем или иным способом время жизни переменной фьючерса, если так хочется `async`...

Comment: *"лучшее решение thread с вызовом detach"* - крайне дурной совет. Создавать потоки на каждый чих - плохо само по себе, а также массово бросать их, вызывая `detach` - откровенный говнокод.

Comment: @user7860670 Я не говорю о том, хорошо это или плохо; я рассказал, как решить **конкретную** задачу - поток без блокировки и ожидания выполнения..

Comment: @user7860670 предложите тогда что-то более дельное)

Comment: Нет, вы рассказали как наложить себе мешок проблем.  А ведь потом сюда кто-нибудь заглянет и потащит это в прод.

Comment: @ComeInRage Я же уже предложил.

Comment: @user7860670 я не вижу где. Все что я вижу - невнятная критика. "Ваш способ плохой. Почему - не скажу и вообще, сами разбирайтесь". Простой всех потоков из пула? Ну это решается только неблокирующими алгоритмами, моя задача явно не об этом.